# Having trouble pushing to github, issue with openssl

Tags: git, github, openssl, freebsd

Hello I am having trouble pushing to git hub.

My git version is 2.17.

When I do `sudo git push -u origin master`

I get `fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/rielt12/Project.git/': OpenSSL was built without TLS 1.2 support`

I tried updating openssl to 1.0.2j. What can I do about this problem?

Comment: Is your openssl installation provided by your distribution, or did you install it manually?

Comment: It’s freebsd so I did pkg install openssl. So to answer: provided by distribution

Comment: Why are you running `git` with `sudo`? Are you entirely sure that the `git` on root's `$PATH` is version 2.17? (It might be different from the one on your regular user's `$PATH`.

Comment: Same result w/o sudo

Comment: @ArielBaron just tests in FreeBSD 11.1 and working fine, try `pkg update && pkg upgrade -y`, openssl version: `OpenSSL 1.0.2k-freebsd `

Comment: Which version of FreeBSD is this? Is it possible that git was compiled and thus links to the system OpenSSL instead of the one installed by ports/pkg? You can check with `ldd /usr/local/bin/git`.

Comment: I have freebsd version 9.2.19. That's the latest I can use on a 32bit machine. The output of  'ldd /usr/local/bin/git' is :{libz.so.6 =>/lib/libz.so.6 (0x28229000)
        libiconv.so.2 => /usr/local/lib//libiconv.so.2 (0x2823d000)
        libthr.so.3 => /lib/libthr.so.3 (0x28335000)
        libc.so.7 => /lib/libc.so.7 (0x28356000)
}

Comment: In that case I believe you have to use ports to compile `git`, to have it linked with OpenSSL from ports. `pkg remove git && cd /usr/ports/devel/git && make install clean`

Answer (score 0):

git support for https URLs comes from the curl. So both CURL must be enabled for the package or git port and your curl install must be built with OpenSSL from ports.